# Using a python function to replace characters in specific column then throws TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Tags: python, pandas, function, jupyter-notebook, series

I want to use clean_currency method below to strip out commas and dollar signs from Savings ($) column and put into a new column called 'Savings_Clean'.

```
def clean_currency(curr):
    return float(curr.replace(",", "").replace("$", ""))

clean_currency("$60,000")#The output is proof that function is working
```

> Output: 60000.0

How to I clean Savings ($) column, because when I put `clean_currency(df.Savings)` I get the following error: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`

Comment: Try returning `curr.replace(",", "").replace("$", "").astype(float)`. To cast a series to another type, there is `astype`.

Comment: IT WORKS! but instead of using `.astype(float)`, is there another way to call the function and achieve the same purpose while using `return float()` on the series?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand: I guess you want to use that function to convert normal strings like `"$60,000"` also, so you want function to behave accordingly?

Comment: That's it. I want the function to convert the strings and work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work with ordinary strings and also the `pd.Series` that contain strings, an if guard can be used:

```py
def clean_currency(curr):
    if isinstance(curr, str):
        return float(curr.replace(",", "").replace("$", ""))
    return curr.str.replace(",", "").str.replace("$", "").astype(float)
```

Now it will look the argument passed `curr` and if it is a `str`ing, cast with `float`, otherwise assume it is a series and use `astype`. (note that we use `str` accessor for replacing the series).

```
>>> clean_currency("$60,000")
60000.0

>>> clean_currency(pd.Series(["$60,000", "$120,000", "$1,000,000"]))
0      60000.0
1     120000.0
2    1000000.0
dtype: float64
```